# Merge two arrays of dictionaries with specific terms

Tags: python

I have the following data:

```
{
    "color" : "black",
    "cars" : [{
        "type": "mercedes",
        "number": 2131231
    }, {
        "type": "BMW",
        "number": 453435
    }],
}
```

I have a field called `self.merged_cars`. I would like to merge the `cars` with `merged_cars` so the the `merged_cars` would look like (`merged_cars` is empty at the moment):

```
"merged_cars" : [{
    "type": "mercedes",
    "number": 2131231,
    "color" : "black"
}, {
    "type": "BMW",
    "number": 453435,
    "color" : "black"
}]
```

The `merged_cars` field won't contain duplicates (same `type`, `number` and `color`). What I tried to do is:

```
{k: v for d in (data['cars'] + self.merged_cars) for k, v in d.items()}
```

But it looks like it is not the right way. Is it possible get a suggestion of a "clean", easy to understand way?

**EDIT**: A better example:

```
"merged_cars" : [{
    "type": "volkswagen",
    "number": 4354312,
    "color" : "white"
}, {
    "type": "BMW",
    "number": 453435,
    "color" : "black"
}]
```

The merge data of:

```
{
    "color" : "black",
    "cars" : [{
        "type": "mercedes",
        "number": 2131231
    }, {
        "type": "BMW",
        "number": 453435
    }],
}
```

will be:

```
"merged_cars" : [{
    "type": "volkswagen",
    "number": 4354312,
    "color" : "white"
}, {
    "type": "BMW",
    "number": 453435,
    "color" : "black"
},{
    "type": "mercedes",
    "number": 2131231,
    "color" : "black"
}]
```

Notices that `BMW` is a duplicate.

Comment: Please provide a full [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); you're a few steps short, and *we* shouldn't have to provide those, nor to figure out what your current code does.
BTW, if `merged_cars` is empty, then this is a reformatting, not a merge.

Comment: It appears to me that your present code isn't properly promoting the sub-dict fields.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, this is too complex for a list or dictionary comprehension and it would be best if you go old school with `for` loop.

Following code should do the trick.

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

merged_cars = [{
    "type": "volkswagen",
    "number": 4354312,
    "color": "white"
}, {
    "type": "BMW",
    "number": 453435,
    "color": "black"
}]

data = {
    "color": "black",
    "cars": [{
        "type": "mercedes",
        "number": 2131231
    }, {
        "type": "BMW",
        "number": 453435
    }],
}

data_color = data['color']
new_merged_cars_list = []
for car in data['cars']: # no need to merge merged_cars
    merged_car = {}
    for key, value in car.items():
        merged_car[key] = value
    merged_car['color'] = data_color
    if merged_car not in merged_cars:
        new_merged_cars_list.append(merged_car)

merged_cars.extend(new_merged_cars_list)

pp(merged_cars)
```

Output :

```
[{'color': 'white', 'number': 4354312, 'type': 'volkswagen'},
 {'color': 'black', 'number': 453435, 'type': 'BMW'},
 {'color': 'black', 'number': 2131231, 'type': 'mercedes'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i personally would make merged cars into a dictionary, where every key is a string of (color + number + type) and the values are the car objects. Then adding the new car data is simple and fast, and getting all of the cars out is just merged_cars.values()

```
merged_cars = { 
  "white4354312volkswagen": {
      "type": "volkswagen",
      "number": 4354312,
      "color" : "white"
    }, 
  "black453435BMW": {
    "type": "BMW",
    "number": 453435,
    "color" : "black"
  }
}

color = data["color"]
for car in data["cars"]:
  key = color + str(car['number']) + car['type']
  merged_cars[key] = car

print(merged_cars.values())
```